# Regex split for words containing periods

Tags: c#, regex, split

Can someone tell me how to modify this regex to allow periods in a string?

`string[] parts = Regex.Split(s, @"\b|[^\.#_a-zA-Z0-9()=><!%]");`

If I provide the string: `"HELLO ABC.123"`

This regex is returning `{"HELLO", "ABC", ".", "123"}`

I want to return `{"HELLO", "ABC.123"}`

Please forgive my noobishness for regex patterns.

EDIT: I am using C# 3.5

Comment: Different languages have different regex functions built-in (C# has `Regex.Split()`; php has `preg_split()`) - what language are you using? It looks like C#, but should be specified so we know if you're using the right function.

Comment: Then you should have put C♯ in the tag set so that those of us who ignore Microsoft can block it.

Comment: @tchrist - thanks for the helpful comment....My question pertains more to the regex pattern, which is why I only tagged it with regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b` matches on both sides of the period in `ABC.123`.
You can change it to avoid that. For example:

```
(?<![\w.])(?=[\w.])|(?<=[\w.])(?![\w.])
```

Giving the complete quoted expression:

```
@"(?<![\w.])(?=[\w.])|(?<=[\w.])(?![\w.])|[^\w.#()=><!%]+"
```

You may want to add the `#()=><!%` characters to all the character classes.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `\b` from `\b|[^\.#_a-zA-Z0-9()=><!%]`, and use:

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split(s, @"[^#_a-zA-Z0-9()=><!%]");
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it still splits the string into 4 parts, not 2.